# Sequelize query by virtual field

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a schema that has 2 fields. one records the user and the other one is a virtual field based on the first field.

```
sequelize.define("Invoice", {
  is_processing_by: { 
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: "usertable",
    referencesKey: "id",
    allowNull: false
  },
  is_processing: { 
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get: function() {
      return this.get("is_processing_by")
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to do

```
Invoice.find({where: {is_processing: 123}})
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Unhandled rejection AssertionError: expected {
  message: 'column Invoice. is_processing does not exist',
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  original: {
  [error: column Invoice.is_processing does not exist]
....
```

Does anyone know what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: As far as i understand virtual fields can only be used after the data has been retrieved from the database and are used for validation or as convenience methods. You can't use them in a query since they aren't a part of the database. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes#virtual

Comment: @GrimurD I see. I was thinking it would be convenient to generate a virtual field like `expiredAfterTenMinutesAndUsedBySomeUse` base on 2-3 fields and query it directly instead of querying with a lot of conditions.. I guess there is no easier way to do it maybe?

Comment: You could always create a class method on the model so you could for example do something like models.someModel.getAllExpiredWithSomeParameter(). But i'd personally do it in a service/business layer instead of on the model itself and call call that from my UI layer.

Comment: I see. that makes sense too. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For everyone struggling with this (as I use to) you can just use a portion of raw SQL to create a virtual column and use it to sort your rows. Like this:

```
const { literal } = require('sequelize')
...
const attributes = Object.keys(Users.rawAttributes)
const users = await Users({
  attributes: [
    ...attributes,
    [literal(`
      coalesce(
        nickname,
        concat("firstName", ' ', "lastName")
      )
    `),
    'name']
  ],
  ...
  order: [[literal('"name"'), 'asc']]
})
```

Hope helps someone ;)